# Correct calculation for a quantum black hole (example: LHC)?

Tags: general-relativity

What is the right equation to calculate a quantum black hole? As an example I like to take the figures from LHC. 
http://lhc-machine-outreach.web.cern.ch/lhc-machine-outreach/beam.htm

Top Energy beam: 362 MJ;
Collision Area: 16 microns;
Energy of 2 Protons: 14 TeV;
Velocity Proton: 0.999999991c;
Radius of proton: 1.32*10^-15m

My assumption: simply replace mass by relativistic energy.
Then the Schwarzschild-Radius can be calculated by: 
 $$\ R_s = \frac {2G*E \sqrt{(1-\frac{v^2}{c^2})}} {c^4} $$

with E=14TeV, the result is: Rs = 3.52 *10^-54m , which is way below planck length. Add possible characteristics like Hawking Radiation... So no quantum black hole in near future? Is my calculation correct? Or do I have to use the Energy of the total beam?

Comment: What about a quantum black hole do you want to calculate?

Comment: I just need a confirmation, if I need do the calculation for two protons, a fraction of the beam or the total beam? And is the use of relativistic energy correct?